# Saving content of individual cells within a column as separate JSON files

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, json

Is there a way to create a collection of JSON Files in a folder based on the content of individual cells in a column in excel?

So basically, I have a spreadsheet with a column starting with cell B12 to B26. Each cell contains a JSON script. I want a VBA that would convert each of these cells into a separate JSON File and create a collection in a folder so I can run in Postman.

Note: Each cell contains a lengthy (40 lines within 1 cell) JSON Script.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Not much Owen, I'm not an expert in this area. I've formulated my cell to create a JSON script. Now I need a VBA to convert the content of that cell to a JSON File..

Comment: http://excelerator.solutions/2017/08/24/convert-excel-to-json-using-vba/

suggest a way of converting/exporting to JSON but my job is actually easier as I have no variables. All I want is to have VBA linked to button that would export contents of cells within a column to multiple JSON files.

Comment: ++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842122/export-cell-range-to-json-data

Comment: I would say adapt the second item you linked to (the stackoverflow one) , probably adding a loop to iterate through all your cells. making sure to change the file name over each iteration.